# Prolog: If one of the rules of a rule failed, then stop the program , else work as usually

Tags: prolog

It is interesting for me if there is any built-in tool, in Prolog, that would work for the following example:

```
parentRole(X,Y,Z):- parent(X,Y), male(X), !, Z=='father', !.
parentRole(X,Y,Z):- parent(X,Y), Z=='mother'.
```

I want the rule `parent(X,Y)` to stop the program (+return false) if `parent(X,Y)` failed, in rule #1, else go on as usually.

This way I'd be able to write:

```
parentRole(X,Y,Z):- parent(X,Y), male(X), !, Z=='father', !.
parentRole(X,Y,Z):- Z=='mother'.
```

Suppose facts are:

`parent(myMom, i)
 male(i)`

I expect for the scope:

`parentRole(notMyMom, i, 'mother')`

the program to stop and return false, but in the real, it fails at `parent(X,Y)` in the 1st rule, and tries to satisfy the 2nd, and it return true as `Z=='mother'`

Thanks.

Comment: @TomasBy For example, when i call `parentRole(notMyFather, me, 'mother')`, I expect the first rule to stop the program, but actually it tries the 2nd one and it returns true.

Comment: Not sure but i think  you want this for a specific parents `\+ parent(a,b),!.`  Means if your database does not contain any `specific a,b` then simply stop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want

```
parentRole(X,Y,Z) :-
  ( parent(X,Y) ->
    ( male(X) -> Z == 'father'
    ; Z == 'mother' ).
  ; fail ).
```

which is the same as

```
parentRole(X,Y,Z) :-
  parent(X,Y),
  ( male(X) -> Z == 'father' ; Z == 'mother' ).
```

Now your example fails, as expected.

Your comment: try this formatting

```
parentRole(X,Y,Z) :-
  ( parent(X,Y) ->
    ( male(X) ->
      ( Z == 'father' ->
        write('father')
      ; fail )
    ; ( Z == 'mother' ->
        write('mother')
      ; fail ) )
  ; fail ).
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to define a separate rule that verifies the gender.

```
parentRole(X, Y, Z) :- parent(X, Y), parentGender(X, Z).

parentGender(X, 'father') :- male(X).
parentGender(X, 'mother') :- \+ male(X).
```

`parentRole` now only has one rule, so it will fail immediately if `parent` fails.

Comment: It's a very nice way to re-write my code, but it is interesting if there is something built-in. I saw the example with `->`, and it seemed it was what i'm looking for, but i didn't managed to make it work.  
                                                                                       `parentRole(X,Y,Z) :-
  ( parent(X,Y) ->
    ( male(X) -> 
     (Z == 'father' ->  
         (write('father'); fail
            ); 
         Z == 'mother' -> 
         (write('mother'); fail
            )
        ); fail
    ); fail
  ).`